# How do I make an input value (from a print,scan statement) become the first value of a vector produced by my loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I am writing a program in C that models the velocity over time of a parachuting person using an approximation. This is for a beginners programming class and I need a little help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main()
{
int i,j,h;
float v[11];
float t[11];
float c,m;

printf("enter initial time\n");
scanf("%f",&v[0]);
printf("enter inital velocity\n");
scanf("%f",&t[0]);
printf("enter drag coefficent\n");
scanf("%f",&c);
printf("enter mass\n");
scanf("%f",&m);

for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
v[i+1]=(v[i]+(32-(c*v[i]*v[i])/m)*(h));
h=((t[i]+1)-t[i]);
t[i+1]=(t[i]+1);
}

for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        printf("%f %f\n",t[j],v[j]);
    }
}
```

I want to make it so I can input the initial velocity so that it is read as 'v' when i=0 and
the initial time to read as 't' when i=0. The remaining values of 'v' and 't' I want to come from my loop equation. Then I want them to print so I can graph the data.

When I run it as i have it above, I get the following error message,

```
para.c:8:12: error: ‘v’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 (double *) v[11];
        ^
para.c:8:12: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
para.c:9:12: error: ‘t’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 (double *) t[11];
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int i,j,h;
   (double *) v[11];
   (double *) t[11];
   (double *) c,m;
```

should be declared as

```
   int i,j,h;
   double v[11];
   double t[11];
   double c,m;
```

since you are not using arrays of pointers to double, you are using arrays of double!

---

Next compuler issue will be the `v(i)` access to your array. It is done by `v[i]`.

---

Next logical issue are your for(...) loops:

```
   for (i=0;i=10;)
```

for is defined as for(INITIALISATION; LOOP CONDITION; LOOP INCREMENT) 
your loop condition `"i=10"` will always evaluate to "true", because you are assigning i!! you need to say "`i == 10`", ore even better "`i < 11`". 
Next you do not define a loop increment, resulting in a second reason for infinite looping! 
increment your loop counter at each iteration, so it does count the iterations! 
This results in:

```
   for (i=0; i < 10; i++)
```

---

Next logical issue are your Semikolons right AFTER the "for" and BEFORE the "{"-Block. 
this means, that your loop will loop over the ";", and when it is finished, it will execute the body of "{" ONCE,

---

Next, you do not sanitize your input. If you enter a weight of "0.0", there is a devision by zero, killing your programm.

---

and last, you should read not the elements v[1] and t[1] from the user, but v[0] and t[0]. 
Your way will work - but my be not give you the required result (you will override it by garbage in your first loop)

Sincerely,

Johannes

Comment: Also `scanf("%lf",v[1]);` should be `scanf("%lf",&v[0]);`

Comment: @EGOrecords thank you for the very helpful information. I have reworked my code but I have one more problem, that maybe you can help me with. The loop runs but returns insane values. I know what my answers should be by doing the calculations on paper.           1.000000 1.000000
2.000000 1045711.250000
3.000000 -2732734208.000000                               
These are my first 3 values returned when i run my program using the values 1 for t[0] and v[0], 0.5 for c and 200 for m. I am expecting much lower values that eventually max out near 120.00 at 10 seconds.

Comment: I put my new code above, I think I am having an issue with how my loop is running.

Comment: your second line of your main loop: you calculate "(t[i]+1)-t[i]", dont you mean "(t[i+1]-t[i])" (I have not the time to do your physics, I just want to point out some strange lines!